# How do i create android application to integrated with wordpress?

Tags: android, android-studio, wordpress, wordpress-theming

1)How do I create android application which integrated with wordpress website? and please give me perfect solution and references.

2)I had completed my wordpress websites and also try simple plugin of wordpress json api.

*https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=json

3) I found where i need to create my custom web services so if i got something that create my own custom web service which I used in my application.

4) I tried to fix it with simple static data but I realise that it would give bad impression and helpless app if I do that.

5) Give me any reference and perfect example regarding android application integrated with wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, This is my own example of integrating android with wordpress.

1. Install Wordpress Rest APi plugin (Which you have already done)
2. Go through the documentation: http://v2.wp-api.org/
3. Get postman running on your machine https://www.getpostman.com/, and learn how to use it. http://www.sitepoint.com/api-building-and-testing-made-easier-with-postman/
4. Try to make a simple request: http://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts, It should print out in Json format and you are good to go.
5. Use [jsonschema2pojo.org](http://jsonschema2pojo.org) to generate plain Java Objects from JSON or JSON-Schema.
6. Learn how to consume API's, I recommend using Retrofit, learn how to use it. You can start here: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit
7. Create a simple MainActivity and model to test your data, just to see how it works.

If you already have a good knowledge of android development, I think this info should get you started with developing a Wordpress android app.

Comment: 4th one link - http://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts, 5th http://consuming%20apis%20with%20retrofit/ are not working links..give me once more after checking it.

Comment: 5th link now works, for 4th link, You have to replace your website URL with "yourwebsite.com"

Comment: @TosinOnikute thanks for this answer helped a lot. i am trying to make an app for wordpress website which uses some kind of plugin for login/signup. need to make some rest calls to create/delete users, but could not find those apis. can you help?